# Delphi - show a console app from SW_HIDE state

Tags: delphi, console-application

I have a console application in Delphi, what i start from an other application this way:

```
FillChar(ExecInfo, SizeOf(ExecInfo), 0);
With ExecInfo Do Begin
  cbSize :=       SizeOf(ExecInfo);
  fMask :=        SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
  Wnd :=          GetActiveWindow();
  lpVerb :=       PChar('runas');
  lpFile :=       PChar(FsCurrentPath + 'Install\Install_Elevated.exe');
  lpDirectory :=  PChar(FNew.sBinDir);
  lpParameters := PChar(sl.DelimitedText);
  nShow :=        SW_HIDE
End;
ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo);
```

In some condition i would like to make it show itself (take in SW_SHOWNORMAL state). How can i do it?

This way it does not show:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_SHOW);
```

Even not this way:

```
BringWindowToTop(GetConsoleWindow);
SetActiveWindow(GetConsoleWindow);
SetForegroundWindow(GetConsoleWindow);
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_SHOW)
```

But it shows itself this way:

```
MessageBox(GetConsoleWindow, PChar(IntToStr(GetConsoleWindow)), PChar(''), MB_SETFOREGROUND);
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_SHOW);
```

But of course i dont want this message box.

What is the problem?

Comment: maybe some tricks from http://superuser.com/a/404246 can help. Also maybe you would also need to show/activate window of `Application.Handle`

Comment: @Arioch It's a console subsystem app. Why would it contain the VCL? Why would the VCL win does be related to the console window?

Comment: Would it be foolish to suggest that you don't pass SW_HIDE

Comment: Did you try calling `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_SHOW)` twice?

Comment: I call it twice and the window shows up. Wow. Thank you.

But i still think this is stupid somehow. :) Or at least i would like to know what happen when i call it twice.

Comment: @trob - You're welcome. I explained why I wanted you to try to call ShowWindow again in the answer I posted. Although I can't say with exact certainty that this is the case (I wasn't successful with duplicating the problem), this is what I believe is happening.

Comment: even DLL has TApplication, even Service has. TApplication is not VCL-specific

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

"the nCmdShow value is ignored in the first call to ShowWindow if the program that launched the application specifies startup information in the structure."

Comment: @Sertac, we got to the reason of the solution at the same time. :)

Comment: @trob - I knew that when I posted my first comment ;). I didn't post an answer since I couldn't duplicate - waited for confirmation.

Comment: @Arioch'The `TApplication` is only in DLLs if `Vcl.Forms` is declared anywhere. And actually `TApplication` *is* VCL specific. It's defined in a VCL unit. Firemonkey has its own `TApplication` too. Services have it, yes, because Delphi's Service implementation is in VCL. Actually, a service's `TServiceApplication` is defined in `Vcl.SvcMgr`

Comment: @Arioch'The: TApplication is not available in a console application unless you add `Forms` to the uses clause. I'm amazed that you are not aware of this fact. (You can test it yourself; File->New->Other->Console application, put `WriteLn(Application.Handle);` after `begin` and hit F9. Does it compile?)

Comment: I meant to say DLLs *and console apps*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell passes the information you supply with `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` through `CreateProcess()` to the console application, which honors that information when you first try to show the console window.

The documentation for [`ShowWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> *nCmdShow* [in]
>   Type: `int`
>
> Controls how the window is to be shown. **This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls `ShowWindow`, if the program that launched the application provides a [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331.aspx) structure**. Otherwise, the first time `ShowWindow` is called, the value should be the value obtained by the `WinMain` function in its `nCmdShow` parameter. In subsequent calls, this parameter can be one of the following values...

So, the first time you call `ShowWindow`, the `SW_HIDE` that was passed to `ShellExecuteEx()` takes effect. In the subsequent calls, the parameter you specify takes effect instead.